# Google Charts API - QR Code

Tags: qr-code

I am using Google Charts API to generate QR code as referred in this link https://www.gregorystrike.com/2011/01/26/how-to-use-google-charts-api-to-generate-your-own-qr-code/

In this as the parameters are visible it seems to be insecure

Users can change the values available in the parameters using developer tools like inspector element of Firefox. Is there a secure way to generate QR codes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

QR codes are insecure anyway, anyone can see the data you place in it, by using any reader.

If want to use QR Codes in any sort of secure sense or to store sensitive data you will have to manage encryption and decryption of that data yourself, there a few encrypted examples but its not a heavily used function. Now we are past the Fab stage of QR Codes, they mainly used like barcodes for identification, with the ability to store more information if needed and the odd URL embedded link.

Although the limit is quite large this is still a limit to the amount of data you can place in a QR Code.

[image]

Lots of information on the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code